# Why is my simple HTML link not working despite seemingly correct code

Tags: html, hyperlink

I create a simple one page website with text using Big Rock's webcreator. I tried to link one of the lines one the page using HTML in the following way:

```
    <a href="iimk.ac.in/faculty-profiles/ASHOK-THOMAS">iimk.ac.in/faculty- 
    profiles/ASHOK-THOMAS</a>
```

The hyperlink however is not working. I would like to fix the error in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** your link is not correct as it doesn't covers the proper URL of the page:

```
<a href="https://iimk.ac.in/faculty-profiles/ASHOK-THOMAS">iimk.ac.in/faculty- 
    profiles/ASHOK-THOMAS</a>
```

Visit this link to see the proper working of the hyperlink:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFSB9.png

Answer (score -2):

your link is not correct with the https formatting so just use this

```html
    <a href="https://iimk.ac.in/faculty-profiles/ASHOK-THOMAS">iimk.ac.in/faculty- 
    profiles/ASHOK-THOMAS</a>
```

Comment: Still not working. Using Big Rock's website builder

Comment: There should be nothing wrong I tested it myself I think it might be the builder